# Python Inherit from one class but override method calling another class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

Let say I have 3 classes: A, B and C. A is a base class for B and B is for C. Hierarchy is kept normally here, but for one method it should be different. For C class it should act like it was inherited from A.

For example like this:

```
class A(object):
    def m(self):
        print 'a'

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        super(B, self).m()
        print 'b'

class C(B):
    def m(self):
        super(A, self).m()
        print 'c'
```

So basically it should work like this:

```
a = A()
a.m()
a

b = B()
b.m()
a
b

c = C()
c.m()
a
c
```

But it is not going to work for C class, because I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'm'
```

To solve this for C class I could inherit from class A, but I want to inherit everything from B and for that specific method `m` call super for base class A. I mean that method is one exception. Or should I call it somehow differently for class C in order to work?

How can I do that?

Comment: did you try `A.m(self)` instead of using `super`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger no I didn't, but now I tried it and it works perfectly. Thanks. You can post it as answer, because it solved my problem

Comment: for that to work, A.m() must be a class method

Comment: @fixmycode But it is a class method isn't it?

Comment: No, it’s an unbound method and you are providing the `self` parameter manualy

Comment: You _could_ call `super(B, self).m()` in the `C.m` method. But I think  Mathias's more direct approach is clearer.

Comment: @PM2Ring calling `super(B, self).m()` will print `a b c`, but it should call only `A` and then `C`.

Comment: @Andrius Seems that you got confused with `super()`.  `super(SomeClass, someobject)` will lookup attributes in the class that **follows** `SomeClass` in the MRO of `someobject`. In your case `super(A, self).m()` refers to `object.m(self)`, which clearly does not exist.

Comment: @Andrius: the call to `super(B, self).m()` in class `C` produces the expected output here ("a c") using Python 2.7.x

Comment: @Andrius: No it doesn't, because it calls the `.m` method of `B`'s _parent_, i.e., `A`. I _did_ test the code before posting my comment. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring yes you are right. I really got confused and thought it would resolve to both A and B being called so I didn't even tested myself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `super` call, python will inspect the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) of your class to determine which class to use when calling the function you want.

Since you want to short-circuit this behaviour, you can explicitly state the class you want to use the method from with:

```
class C(B):
    def m(self):
        A.m(self)
        print 'c'
```

Answer (score 8):

There are in fact two ways to solve this: you can shortcut the call to `super()` and totally bypass the mro as in Mathias Ettinger's answer, or you can just issue the *correct* call to `super()`:

```
class C(B):
    def m(self):
        super(B, self).m()
        print 'c'
```

Remember that `super()` expects as first argument the class from which it should start looking up the mro. It's usually the class in which the call is made, but you can pass another class upper in the mro if you want.